# E: The package linux-headers-4.2.0-38 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: archive

I recently upgraded my laptop, but in the middle of the process someone in my house did something on it which caused it to stop connecting to wireless. I also can't open Ubuntu software centre or install anything. If I try to do it, the following message appears:

> E: The package linux-headers-4.2.0-38 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Can you connect to the internet at all?  If you can't, the system wouldn't be able to access the archive.

Comment: I can't connect wirelessly, but  if I connect the laptop through ethernet cable it connects.